# injecting properties in camel route from wildfly modules

Tags: apache-camel, wildfly, switchyard

I am using SwithcYard 2.0.0.Beta1. Application server is WildFly 8.1. I want to load properties from modules. 
As example I have a module /wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/study/configuration/test
my module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.study.configuration" slot="test">  
    <resources>  
        <resource-root path="."/>  
    </resources>  
</module>
```

This is properties file:

```
user=foo
password=bar
provider=CryptoProvider
directory=domain;login:pwd@host/dir?password=pwd&preMove=backup&move=processed&moveFailed=error&charset=UTF-8
```

This is how I include that module in wildfly profile:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0">
        <global-modules>
            <module name="org.study.configuration" slot="test"/>
        </global-modules>
```

And now I want to load that properties in my camel route:

```
.to("smb://{{directory}}")
```

or 
in bean

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", {{provider}});
```

Is it possible? how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but as long as your properties are in the file you have to load it first.

What you define in the module - it is just a class path for your application.

If you use Java DSL:

```
Properties myProps = new Properties();

Stream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MyAppProp.properties");
myProps.load(is);       
System.getProperties().putAll(myProps);
```

If you use Spring DSL just define regular Spring properties.

a. with Spring bean namespace

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>MyAppProp.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

b. with Spring context namespace

```
<context:property-placeholder location="MyAppProp.properties"/>
```

Then you can use them inside Camel route as you said:

```
.to("smb://{{directory}}")
```

PS. you have an ability to define properties directly in the module.xml as well

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.study.configuration" slot="test">
  <properties>
    <property name="directory" value="myTestDirectory"/>
  </properties>
  ...
```